# Flutter webview black screen when keyboard is popping up

Tags: android, flutter, android-10.0, flutterwebviewplugin

I have included flutter module inside my android project and flutter module contains webview ***(flutter_inappwebview)*** which I am using to load app url's.

I am opening a webview page which has text fields to enter the data. when I click on text field to enter the data the keyboard is poping up and the ***screen becomes completely black***.

***Logs are filling with below error***

```
E/InputMethodManager: b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=134 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebView.InAppWebView{1df7162 VFEDHVCL. .F...... 0,0-1440,2308}
```

***flutter logs***

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /Users/prabhukuppala/Documents/FlutterDevelopment/flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (2 weeks ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/prabhukuppala/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/prabhukuppala/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/prabhukuppala/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 201.7846.93

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5556 • android-x64 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert this in scaffold:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

Comment: Perfectt., been struggling for a few days with this while creating a barcode scanner app, and its just a single line of code lol. Thanks mate!!

Comment: I understand setting to false will prevent the scaffold body from resizing to accommodate the keyboard, which might not be desirable sometimes. Is there a way to allow this resizing while keeping the camera on? Or there's no way around it..